# Adding columns based on values in same group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I had a question that is borne out of data that is formatted in a way that isn't optimal to do "versus analysis". For example, we have one record per name per game, and we also have data for the player they played against (always 2 records per game; think center vs. center or pg vs. pg in basketball etc).

Current data:

```
    uid   name  field1  field2  field3
    1     bob       35      0       49
    1     evan       4      24      29
    2     bob       39      47      26
    2     mike       6      40      49
    3     bob       48      7       7
    3     evan      18      20      11
    4     bob        3      49      41
    4     evan      25      35      23
```

Desired Output:

```
uid     name    versus  field1  field2  field3
1        bob    evan    same as above 
1        evan   bob
2         bob   mike
2        mike   bob
3         bob   evan
3        evan   bob 
4         bob   evan    
4        evan   bob
```

The goal of this re-arrangement/addition being that now I can do group-by analysis on one player vs. another over multiple games to find how they do on average in that matchup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is just 2 entries for each game, you could try grouping and reversing the names.

```
df['versus'] = df.groupby('uid')['name'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the other player's name, you should go for Rohith's solution. You can also use `merge` and `query` to get other players' statistics as well:

```
(df.merge(df, on='uid')
  .query('name_x != name_y')
)
```

Output

```
      uid  name_x      field1_x    field2_x    field3_x  name_y      field1_y    field2_y    field3_y
--  -----  --------  ----------  ----------  ----------  --------  ----------  ----------  ----------
 1      1  bob               35           0          49  evan               4          24          29
 2      1  evan               4          24          29  bob               35           0          49
 5      2  bob               39          47          26  mike               6          40          49
 6      2  mike               6          40          49  bob               39          47          26
 9      3  bob               48           7           7  evan              18          20          11
10      3  evan              18          20          11  bob               48           7           7
13      4  bob                3          49          41  evan              25          35          23
14      4  evan              25          35          23  bob                3          49          41
```

Comment: Thanks for this response as well. I did just need the player name but this is a great way to concatenate multiple row information into one.